# JUnit4 - AssertionFailedError: No tests found

Tags: android, testing, junit, junit4, android-espresso

I'm using AndroidJUnitRunner with Espresso.

I wrote a simple test but always receive this exception. According to Stackoverflow answers, the problem is messing up the JUnit3 and JUnit4 but I have never used JUnit3 in my project.

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.walletsaver.app.test.espresso.SignUpPopupTest

```
package com.walletsaver.app.test.espresso;

import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;

import com.walletsaver.app.activity.LoginActivity;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class SignUpPopupTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void checkSignUpPopup() throws Exception {
        onView(withText("Sign Up")).perform(click());
    }
}
```

Run configuration:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I found the problem.
It was missed code in `build.gradle` in the main module.
If you have this problem I advise to start with adding this line:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot it solved the problem, can you tell why we have to add this?

Comment: @OmerMalik I tried to mention `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` in Run configuration but this didn't have an effect. Then I wrote it directly in `build.gradle` and it helped. It seems it should be set in `defaultConfig` to be visible.

Comment: I read the android documentation and it is mentioned their, I missed the step, thank alot

Comment: as a follow-up, one may see the message "Unable to find instrumentation info for".  To fix that, tell the Android Studio launch configuration to use the specific test runner from the _build.gradle_ file

Comment: For AndroidX, 
testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

Comment: Hi, I have Dynamic Feature Modules in my app. For tests in the Feature Module, I'm using a custom testInstrumentationRunner , which is located in the app module. I'm getting this error
 "Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'"
Any idea how will it work across multiple modules? @Val

Comment: For AndroidX, use `testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3"
}
```

---

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SomeInstrumentedTest {}
```